# How to get value in json that is in between html and php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I was making function that can vote up and down. Basically when I tried to implement jquery ajax in it, it isn't providing the correct value.

my file is something like,

```
<?php
//some data navigation menu and other things here

//my function is here
if($_POST['rate']=='down') {
    $rate=get_post_meta($post->ID,'down',true);
    $rate=$rate+1;
    update_post_meta($post->ID,'down',$rate);
    setcookie(rate, 1, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
    $totaldn=get_post_meta($post->ID,'down',true);
}
```

Now I want that $totaldn to be returned in ajax, but it was returning the old value, so I implemented the header type system and declare it json like,

```
if(isset($_POST['rate'])) {     
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$myData = array();
$myData['abc']="Hello World";
echo json_encode($myData);
```

Now it starts giving me error, that unexpected syntax it is only working when I put this code on top of the file, other wise my jquery ajax code is either returning full html page.

My question how I can put this header type in middle of the html and php without errors

my jquery ajax code is .

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("#bmup").click(function(){
     $.ajax({
      url: window.location,
      type: "POST",
      data: "rate="+$("#bvdn").val(),
  datatype: 'json',
      success: function(mydata){

           $.each( mydata, function( key, val ) {
    alert( val);
  });

          //alert($.getJSON(mydata));
            $("#bmup").html(mydata);           
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    alert("An AJAX error occured: " + status + "\nError: " + error);
      }   
            }); 
        });
    });
```

Comment: Header information has to go at the top. it is semantics. How would you like to read a book with the title in the middle of the book and you have to read half of it to know what it is called? ;) Are you trying to get data from a PHP script?

Comment: `Now I want that $totaldn to be returned in ajax, but it was returning the old value, so I implemented the header type system and declare it json like` Could you explain that?

Comment: do you ever write $rate back to $myData after the increment? also storeing information in cookies is very untypically and unsafe as it can be manipulated on the client side easily

Comment: I am just storing cookie to stop more than one vote per user, and that is for test purpose only, all I want here is updated value of $totaldn ? if I am calling it like function(data) with out header set, it is returning the whole webpage, while setting an invisible field with the value of totaldn is also not working as it is passing old value. What I want here is updated value of vote ?

Comment: You can still echo the `json_encode`'d string and then `JSON.parse` the response in your AJAX. Would that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't try something like this?

```
$totaldn=$rate;
```

And set totaldn in a html element... 
You should test update_post_meta. If it's true, you can considered that its' OK.

Look Wordpress doc :[Link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta)

> Returns meta_id if the meta doesn't exist, otherwise returns true on success and false on failure. NOTE: If the meta_value passed to this function is the same as the value that is already in the database, this function returns false.